# Sql - Assign multiple variables from query result with condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assume the query

`SELECT RecordType, COUNT(*) RecordsCount 
 FROM Records AS 
 WHERE ... 
 GROUP BY RecordType` returns this table:

```
------------------------------
|RecordType   | RecordsCount |
------------------------------
|      1       |    15       |
------------------------------
|      2       |    10       |
------------------------------
|      3       |    8        |
------------------------------
```

I've defined those variables:

```
DECLARE @paymentRecordCount INT = 0;
DECLARE @dataRecordCount INT = 0;
```

I'm looking for a way to set **at once** the both variables -  `@paymentRecordCount` variable to the result of the condition `where RecordType = 1`, and to set the `@dataRecordCount` variable to the result of the condition `where RecordType = 3`.

The only way I've found so far is to compute the select query multiple times something like:
`select @dataRecordCount = RecordsCount from (select ... from ..) where RecordType = 3`
and to do the same for the other variable, like:
 `select @paymentRecordCount = RecordsCount from (select ... from ..) where RecordType = 1`

There is a way to compute the query once and set the both varaibles together?

Comment: Is the method you have tried in your question causing you any issues?  Why is that solution not sufficient?

Comment: @iamdave it works, but I want to know if it's the best approach or I can do that calculation at once?

Comment: @Roni It would also help to see the query that gave you the results you show.  The reason being that the best approach is to pivot your results to 1 row of 3 columns before assigning them to the variables.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks! I've updated with the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    @paymentRecordCount = SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 1 THEN 1 END),
    @dataRecordCount    = SUM(CASE WHEN RecordType = 3 THEN 1 END)
FROM
    Records
WHERE
    ... 
    AND RecordType IN (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a statement with one subquery per `RecordType`, but you have to consider the case when (if) there are multiple values per `RecordType`:

```
declare @table Table (recordtype int, recordscount int)
insert @table values (1, 1);
declare @dataRecordCount int, @paymentRecordCount int;

SELECT
@paymentRecordCount = (SELECT RecordsCount FROM @table WHERE RecordType=1),
@dataRecordCount = (SELECT RecordsCount FROM @table WHERE RecordType=3);


SELECT @dataRecordCount, @paymentRecordCount;
```

Comment: the `ELSE NULL` is redundant - if the condition is not met, the `CASE` expression returns `null` by default.

Comment: Thanks, I like to explicitly set the results.

Comment: Actually, that will result with one of the variables as null. It should be `ELSE <variableName> END` - [See rextester demo.](http://rextester.com/EJAXH93406)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Actually, should use `SUM(CASE)` or `MAX(CASE)` to collapse everything to a single row before assignment to the variables.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, that would probably be better :-)

Comment: @Vladislav Thanks! but it's not working... Just try double insert as `insert @table values (1, 8);
insert @table values (3, 8);` and look in the rersults

Comment: ah... this is embarrassing, sorry for misleading you. I will update my answer with a different approach to the accepted one, just so that I don't delete it. My new suggestion, however, is pseudo-one-statement, because it uses subqueries...